# How to create a buy application prompt on a certain amount of start-up times

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, math, windows-phone-8

In my trial application I am implementing a notification which asks the user whether he/she would like to buy it. I would like this message to be displayed say every other time the application in started up.

I am logging the amount of times the application has been launched by increasing the length of a file named "launchCount" in `IsolatedStorage` like so:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(appStorage.OpenFile("launchCount", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))
{
    writer.BaseStream.SetLength(writer.BaseStream.Length + 1);
}
```

To determin the amount of times the app has been launched I just grab the length of the file in `IsolatedStorage`.

However how can I determine if this variable has a length of 2,4,6,8,10 etc...

I've tried dividing the retrieved length of the variable by 2, but don't know how to check if it is an integer (whole number).

Any Ideas anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: Try something like this pseudocode: `if(variable % 2 == 0) then displayMessage`. It checks that it's an even number, and if so, shows your message.

Comment: Just set a variable (Int) in the file that auto increments, and display the prompt each time the variable is even. Quick and simple.

Comment: growing a file every time someone launches an app seems like a bad idea, I know it will take a while to grow to any significance, but still, I think Anon has it better, store the number of times it's launched as an int in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is true:

```
writer.BaseStream.Length % 2 == 0
```

Then you can display the message. Change 2 if you need and other interval.

Comment: What does % 2 == 0 do?

Comment: % gets the remainder after you dived by 2 (in this example). If this is 0, you know it is an even number. If you do % 8 you know it can be divided by 8.

Answer (score 0):

Without beeing 100% sure but I think the following would be more efficient, clear and simple than working with a whole file:

```
private void CheckAppLaunchStatus()
{
    // Application settings
    readonly IsolatedStorageSettings _settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    if (_settings.Contains("AppLunchTimes"))
    {
        value = (int) _settings["AppLunchTimes"];

        if (value % 2 == 0)
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("Would you like to buy the application?", "Trial Version", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel));

        _settings["AppLunchTimes"] = value++;
    }
    else
        _settings.Add(key, 1);
}
```